# How to build a prime generator in Forth?

Tags: gforth

My aim was to build a prime number generator in Forth. Not a Sieve of Eratosthenes but two nested loops who are bruteforcing all combinations of number A and number B. In the sourcecode, I have a word for the loop, for testing if a condition is true and also some attempt in doing the nested loop. But after executing the code with gforth a stack-underflow error is shown. Maybe some kind of dup is missing somewhere, but it's also possible that the i and j index in the loops is wrong. The problem is, that if i change something in the code, the stack is different. That means, after putting out the index number of the for loop to the screen, it's no longer possible to get access to this number. Also i find it's difficult to get access to variables, because Forth doesn't seem to have variables at all. So I created a helper variable, but it's unclear how to use it.

I know, the code looks a bit confusing, can anybody help?

```
variable temp
: numbers
  10 0 do i . loop
;
: cond
  0 dup
  0 = if ." equal 0" endif
;
: plain
10 2 mod .
10 3 mod .
10 4 mod .
10 5 mod .
10 6 mod .
10 7 mod .
10 8 mod .
10 9 mod .
;
: plain2
10 temp !
\ 10 0 do temp @ i mod . loop
\ 10 0 do temp @ . i . loop
10 2 do temp @ i mod . cond loop
;
: cond2 ( n - n )
  10 2 do i 
  10 2 do i 
  mod .
  loop cr loop
;

: main
  \ numbers
  cond2
  \ plain
  \ plain2
;
main
CR bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bugs and repetitions in your code. For example in your `cond` word you put `0` on the data stack then `dup` it and compare stack top value (which is `0`) with `0`. Of course, you will get `true` every time.

It seems that you try to write many words definitions at once and use them in your program without debugging carefully every single word. With `Forth` programming it is better to make (and debug) a few short words and then compose more complicated code with them. I would recommend you to read [Starting Forth book](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth) which describes this approach very well.

Regarding your code -- it is better to rewrite it completely. Here it is:

```
: is-not-divided-by mod 0= INVERT ;

: check-prime-number true SWAP DUP 2 DO DUP I is-not-divided-by ROT AND SWAP loop DROP ;

: is-prime-number DUP 2 > IF check-prime-number ELSE DROP true THEN ; 

: prime-numbers 1 DO I is-prime-number IF I . THEN LOOP ;
```

and now `10 prime-numbers` will print you prime numbers from 1 to 9.